# arraylist of objects, adding objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am a poor programmer but I need some help for an app I have been procrastinating to build. (note sorry for the lack of detail on the first try

I have created an `ArrayList` of `myObject`s that have their own properties. When I created the `myObject` class I created an initializer so that I could add in `myObject` into an `ArrayList` of them. I got it working but I am having problems as the properties of the objects are being overwritten as I loop through my code. Here is a simplified example:

```
myOjbect newMyObject = new myObject
List<myOject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<myObjet>();

try {

    // go through a text file, set some properties of my object...
     myArrayValue = some text input //(sorry i didnt want to put the whole code as its sloppy, but it does return an array) 
     myObject.matrix = myArrayValue; // this value changes as I go through the text file, but in the listOfObects, only the last value is saved to each item in the list
    SetStartDate(somestring1); // another constructor/initializer (sorry i forget the correct terminology) I added to the 'myObject' class. This property sets correctly in the list
    listOfObjects.add(new myObject(newMyObject));
```

Then in my class of `myObject` is have this initializer:

```
public myObject(myObject other){
    matrix = other.matrix;
    startDate = other.startDate;
    // TODO add all the properties here, so that they get copied
}

public SetStartDate(string inputText){
startdate = inputText // or something like that, I dont have the code on this computer
}
```

So the `startDate` property is working, when I loop through the list of items but when I set the `matrix` property, I always end up with the last property value in my main script as the property value for each item in the list.

Any ideas why the `startDate` property works fine but not the `matrix` (which is an array variable)?

thanks

Comment: what are you doing this `public myObject(myObject other)`?? sending an object of same class and making another object?? Parameterized constructor is to send values and to initialize its variables.

Comment: Posting your actual code would help to get an idea what's going wrong.

Comment: - `loop through some code, set some properties of my object...`
what code is in this loop?

Comment: We need ***way*** more details to answer this question.  There's so much missing information about what your code actually *is* and what it's actually doing that we're going to miss that without the actual source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the array elements instead of saving a reference of the array object, you can do this.

```
matrix = Arrays.copyOf(other.matrix, other.matrix.length);
```

Comment: How could this be an answer?  We don't even know what `matrix` actually is!  Why do you think that they're attempting to copy an array across when all they talk about is `ArrayList`?

Comment: @Makoto, "the matrix (which is an array variable)", I guess he is trying to code as per copy constructor coding technique from C++. Clearly the problem says, its the matrix array which is not getting saved. Could you please help me out to mention where did I do any wrong?

Comment: thanks, I think this is the problem. Though it is a deep array, so i will need to loop through it i guess